# Model View Presenter/Controller file structure

Tags: php, web-applications, mvp

I wonder how you most developers separate MVC into different files.
The piece of software I am working on is exclusively AJAX powered, the view has zero logic what to do with the input data, it only has UI logic and all actions, is sent to the controller for processing via a giant switch case by command+arguments(as a POST) request.

eg. 3 Files

- list_inventory.php (view)
- ajax_inventory.php (controller)
- class_inventory.php (model)

In theory, this structure looks absolutely perfect, and it is for most cases, however, as development progresses, there is repeated controller code since each view has it's own controller. Is sharing the same controller a common practice for CRUD apps? Also sometimes the controller has minimal code, eg. 1 set of commands+argument - a one case switch.

Also SEO and stuff is not a concern as it is an intranet web app.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a common controller class or multiple base controller classes, depending on what is their purpose.Thus all the repeating code is in one place, only requiring different controllers to set the proper parameters for the base-class code to work.

For example of a site with news and pages editing part (both have title and content ...) then you make a base controller class that will deal with the common CRUD tasks, only waith for you in the sub-class to set the POST parameters names and to associate them with the real data variables and etc.

If I understood you right, you parse the actions on the server-side in a big fat switch in the PHP, right? Isn't it a better solution to split each action into a separate method in the control and for exmaple use reflection classes to check for validity? This way the dispatching to the right action is don in one single place (somewhere up the hieracy) and you only define the separate action handlers (again, handling common actions in all controllers should be defined somewhere in the parent classes).

Regards.